# Can I use storyboards in Xcode 4.1?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I've seen tutorials (namely [this one](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html)) that explain Xcode 4.x should be able to handle storyboards but I'm using 4.1 and don't see the option when I create a new project.

Even the [iOS docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW55) aren't clear

Do I need to enable it somewhere?

If not, I guess downloading 4.2 should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Xcode 4.2, the Interface Builder user interface for iOS applications is based on the storyboarding of view controllers.

From your link